# Django hidden input being rendered as <td> in html

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using a modelformset to allow the user to add/edit/delete food item's on their restaurant's menu.

```
FoodItemFormset = modelformset_factory(FoodItem, fields = '__all__', can_delete = True)
```

I'm then iterating over all of the forms in my template and displaying them in a table:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Food Item</th>
      <th></th> <!-- empty <th> lines up with hidden input field -->
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    {% for form in food_formset  %}
      <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
          <td>{{ field }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
```

However, that `can_delete` attribute does not only lead to a checkbox being rendered, it also renders the hidden field containing the object's id as an actual table element, leading to an empty gutter between the tables contents.

```
<td><input type="text" name="form-0-name" value="Mozzarella Sticks" maxlength="200" id="id_form-0-name"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="2" id="id_form-0-id"></td> <!-- this just looks like an empty gutter -->
<td><input type="checkbox" name="form-0-DELETE" id="id_form-0-DELETE"></td>
```

Is there a way to get around this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over [`form.visible_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) to only include visible fields.

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <td>{{ field }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

You will also need to render the hidden fields but this doesn't need to be in it's own table cell.

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
```